# Bootstrap navigation menu is not working in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my WordPress theme. But Navigation menu style are not showing properly. Bootstrap is enqueued fine. 
Here is my code for output menu

```
<div class="nav-container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <?php
             wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'    =>    'primary',
                 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                  'container' =>    '<ul>'
                   ) );
                   ?>
               </nav>
      </div>
```

Output of code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

But navigation links are showing without bootstrap navigation styles.
 [check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brehm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would **highly** recommend using a `custom navwalker` for Bootstrap specifically.

Check [this](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) out.

Usage is something like this but check their easy to follow docs using the link above.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
            </a>
    </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `nav` structure according to bootstrap like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>            
          </div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

You can also find this on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m393eav0/)

Comment: Same issue with this code too, bootstrap styles for navigation is not applying . actually my code also working fine without WordPress.

Comment: Do you able to share that buggy menu link somewhere?